# What are the loc and scale parameters in scipy.stats.maxwell?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distribution

The maxwell-boltzmann distribution is given by [image: maxwell-boltzmann]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/MaxwellDistribution/Inline9.gif))</sub>
. The scipy.stats.maxwell distribution uses loc and scale parameters to define this distribution. How are the parameters in the two definitions connected? I also would appreciate if someone could tell in general how to determine the relation between parameters in scipy.stats and their usual definition.

Comment: I'm new to stats and was trying to find this information about the [Edward package](http://edwardlib.org/api/ed/models), so thank you. (I write this comment so that hopefully Google can pick up on the term Edward and the link in case more people have the same question I did, then this can be easier to find.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `loc` parameter *always* shifts the `x` variable. In other words, it generalizes
the distribution to allow shifting `x=0`  to `x=loc`. So that when `loc` is nonzero,

```
maxwell.pdf(x) = sqrt(2/pi)x**2 * exp(-x**2/2), for x > 0
```

becomes

```
maxwell.pdf(x, loc) = sqrt(2/pi)(x-loc)**2 * exp(-(x-loc)**2/2), for x > loc.
```

---

[The doc string](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html) for `scipy.stats.maxwell` states:

> A special case of a `chi` distribution, with `df = 3`, `loc = 0.0`, and
>   given `scale = a`, where `a` is the parameter used in the [Mathworld
>   description](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaxwellDistribution.html).

So the scale corresponds to the parameter `a` in the equation

[image]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/MaxwellDistribution/Inline9.gif))</sub>

In general you need to [read the distribution's doc string](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/stats.html) to know what parameters the distribution has. [The beta distribution](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html), for example, has `a` and `b` shape parameters in addition to `loc` and `scale`.

However, I believe for all continuous distributions,
`distribution.pdf(x, loc, scale)` is identically equivalent to
`distribution.pdf(y) / scale` with `y = (x - loc) / scale`.